# Easy sequences of letters

Tags: letter-sequence

Find the letters to fill the blank.

**T, Q, P, H, H, O, _, _, _**

**T, C, O, D, _**

Hint 1:

> Geometry

Comment: You might want to narrow it down a bit. There are lots of possibilities.

Comment: I'd buy that, yeah. I wasn't worried about *easy*, I was worried about there being too many answers that made sense. The hint ties is down almost completely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**T Q P H H O _ _ _**

> **N D H**: Triangle Quadrilateral Pentagon Hexagon Heptagon Octagon **N**onagon **D**ecagon **H**endecagon

**T C O D _**

> **I**: Tetrahedron Cube Octahedron Dodecahedron Icosahedron

Comment: Quadrangle and Quadrilateral had a [mighty battle](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quadrilateral%2Cquadrangle&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquadrilateral%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquadrangle%3B%2Cc0) and Quadrangle was winning for over 200 years but it has fallen out of favor and Quadrilateral took the only to be overtaken *again* in the last few years!

Comment: The missing letter for #2 is **I**, for reasons similar to the first, just in a higher mode of thinking....

Comment: @EngineerToast Thanks. I wasn't sure which to pick, but I've changed it now

Comment: @Geobits Yeah, just wasn't sure what the other one was, wanted to get an answer in first

Comment: @EngineerToast: I wonder why not "tetragon", given that five-sided figures aren't called "quintilaterals" or "quintangles"?

Answer (score 7):

**T Q P H H O _ _ _**

> **B V N**: This Question Places High Hopes On **B**eing **V**ery **N**arrow

**T C O D _**

> **W**: That Concept Obviously Doesn't **W**ork

:D

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: @JLee: That's because he's being facetious.  Still got farther than I did though.

Comment: +1 for pointing out how broad it is in the form of an answer

Comment: Fortunately, this answer is less accurate now that a hint has been added :)